# HAProxy reqrep with text after last backreference

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to redirect links that point at an old application to a new one. The new application can't handle direct links, so I want to point them to a search, but this search needs to be quoted to work properly. I have tried the following configuration but get 400 Bad Request if I do:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /\?pdf=(.*)  \1\ /newpdf?search=%22\2%22
```

The closest I have come is to remove everything after the last backreference, like this:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /\?pdf=(.*)  \1\ /newpdf?search=%22\2
```

Is it not possible to put anything after the last backreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't text after the backreference.  You are overlooking the nature of the string you are manipating:

```
GET /page?pdf=foo HTTP/1.1 <<< here
```

After the URI there is a space and the HTTP version.  You're capturing that inside `\2`.  Separate it into `\3`, capturing a space and one or more non-space characters, anchored to the end.

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /\?pdf=(.*)(\ [^\ ]+)$  \1\ /newpdf?search=%22\2%22\3
```

A better solution would be to use fetches and the `http-request` request modification capabilities to manipulate the query string.